# customizing ruby .new operator

Tags: ruby, constructor

Let's say I have a class `Foo` and the constructor takes 2 parameters.
Based on these parameters the initialize method does some heavy calculations and stores them as variables in the instance of the class. Object created.

Now I want to optimize this and create a cache of these objects. When creating a new Foo object, I want to return a existing one from the cache if the parameters match. How can I do this?

I currently have a `self.new_using_cache(param1, param2)`, but I would love to have this integrated in the normal `Foo.new()`.
Is this possible in any way?

I can also deduct that using `.new()` combined with a cache is not really syntactical correct. 
That would mean that the method should be called `new_or_from_cache()`.

**clarification**
It's not just about the heavy calculation, it's also preferred because of limiting the amount of duplicate objects. I don't want 5000 objects in memory, when I can have 50 unique ones from a cache. So I really need to customize the .new method, not just the cached values.

Comment: Is this the Flyweight pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Comment: Jeps, that is indeed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Foo
  @@cache = {}

  def self.new(value)
    if @@cache[value]
      @@cache[value]
    else
      @@cache[value] = super(value)
    end
  end

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

end

puts Foo.new(1).object_id #2148123860
puts Foo.new(2).object_id #2148123820 (different from first instance)
puts Foo.new(1).object_id #2148123860 (same as first instance)
```

You can actually define `self.new`, then call `super` if you actually want to use `Class#new`.

Also, this totally approach prevents any instantiation from ever occurring if a new instance isn't actually needed.  This is die to the fact the initialize method doesn't actually make the decision.

Comment: Best answer, and in the way I have implemented it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class Foo
  @@cache = {}
  def initialize prm1, prm2
    if @@cache.key?([prm1, prm2]) then @prm1, @prm2 = @@cache[[prm1, prm2]] else
      @prm1 = ...
      @prm2 = ...
      @@cache[[prm1, prm2]] = [@prm1, @prm2]
    end
  end
end
```

**Edited**

To not create an instance when the parameters are the same as before,

```
class Foo
  @@cache = {}
  def self.new prm1, prm2
    return if @@cache.key?([prm1, prm2])
    @prm1 = ...
    @prm2 = ...
    @@cache[[prm1, prm2]] = [@prm1, @prm2]
    super
  end
end

p Foo.new(1, 2)
p Foo.new(3, 4)
p Foo.new(1, 2)

# => #<Foo:0x897c4f0>
# => #<Foo:0x897c478>
# => nil
```

Comment: Indeed valid answer. However, this doesn't solve the duplicate objects that I want to eliminate from memory.

Comment: Wow, going to try the `def self.new` didn't know that this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with by defining a generic caching module. The module expects your class to implement the "retrieve_from_cache" and "store_in_cache" methods. If those methods don't exist, it doesn't attempt to do any fancy caching.

```
module CacheInitializer
  def new(*args)
    if respond_to?(:retrieve_from_cache) &&
        cache_hit = retrieve_from_cache(*args)
      cache_hit
    else
      object = super
      store_in_cache(object, *args) if respond_to?(:store_in_cache)
      object
    end
  end
end

class MyObject
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar
  extend CacheInitializer

  @cache = {}

  def initialize(foo, bar)
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
  end

  def self.retrieve_from_cache(foo, bar)
    # grab the object from the cache
    @cache[cache_key(foo, bar)]
  end

  def self.store_in_cache(object, foo, bar)
    # write back to cache
    @cache[cache_key(foo, bar)] = object
  end

private
  def self.cache_key(foo, bar)
    foo + bar
  end
end
```

Comment: Update based on your clarification -- these blank cache get/set methods are extensible to do whatever caching strategy you need. If you want to limit to 50 objects, you could maintain a separate queue of cache keys. When you hit the 50 object limit, you could delete one of the keys from the cache hash + queue.

Comment: Nice idea! I am not that far into ruby that I use modules, but it looks nice and clean.

Comment: AFAIK, when you extend `MyObject` with `CacheInitializer`, the `new` method defined in `CacheInitializer` will be the first method tried when you call `MyClass.new`. From there, you can get at the original `MyClass.new` method by calling `super`.

Also, you can reuse `CacheInitializer` in any class, as long as you define `self.retrieve_from_cache` and `self.store_in_cache`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [class-level instance variable](http://blog.codegram.com/2011/4/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby) to store results from previous object instantiations:

```
class Foo
  @object_cache = {}

  def initialize(param1, param2)
    @foo1 = @object_cache[param1] || @object_cache[param1] = expensive_calculation
    @foo2 = @object_cache[param2] || @object_cache[param2] = expensive_calculation
  end

  private
  def expensive_calculation
    ...
  enf
end
```

Comment: Yes, it would solve the problem. However, it's also due to memory limiting, since I would otherwise have around 5000 duplicate objects, and want to restrain them to the possible 50 unique ones. But yes, valid solution for the simplified presented problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know you have reinvented [the factory method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and it's a perfectly valid solution using your name for the factory method. In fact, it's probably better to do it without redefining `new` if anyone else is going to have to understand it.

But, it can be done. Here is my take:

```
class Test

  @@cache = {}

  class << self
    alias_method :real_new, :new
  end

  def self.new p1
    o = @@cache[p1]
    if o
      s = "returning cached object"
    else
      @@cache[p1] = o = real_new(p1)
      s = "created new object"
    end
    puts "%s (%d: %x)" % [s, p1, o.object_id]
    o
  end

  def initialize p
    puts "(initialize #{p})"
  end

end
Test.new 1
Test.new 2
Test.new 1
Test.new 2
Test.new 3
```

And this results in:

```
(initialize 1)
created new object (1: 81176de0)
(initialize 2)
created new object (2: 81176d54)
returning cached object (1: 81176de0)
returning cached object (2: 81176d54)
(initialize 3)
```

Comment: Nice the aliasing! But I also see in sawa's answer that you can just def self.new, that's even a easier way. Still thanks for the insight!

Comment: Indeed, you could do without the aliasing and call `super` in the `self.new` instead.